# Drupal views module

Tags: drupal

Hie

I'm new to drupal development but I'm finding it pretty interesting.

I have created my view and it is displaying the information in my entity submissions database properly. Now I want to have a style where by I have a drop down menu to select the items I want to view. I installed taxonomy view integration and included it in all the taxonomy vocabularies I want to use but then no drop down selection is being seen on the views page.

May someone please help me on how I can have select items to view on my site using views module.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting your issue right - you are going to need a feature called `Exposed filters`. In this case - we could have a dropdown list with a list of terms. Once you select a term from that list - it updates a view showing you the items tagged with that term.

To do what you want you'll need to add a filter titled as `Content: Has taxonomy term` to your view. I have walked through this process and created some screenshots so you could see how that's done.

Hope it helps

1.Creating the filter. By default - it doesn't allow to select values manually. It just allows you to select some predefined ones. Go to Filter `Criteria -> Add`
[image]

2.Setting up your new filter. Find and select the `Content: Has taxonomy term` criteria, click Add and make sure you select `Dropdown` and check the `Expose this filter` checkbox on the next screen
[image]

[image]

[image]

3.That's it! At the bottom you should see your drop down menu. Don't forget to save your brand new view.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. It really helped, I now have the drop down menu and it's now working according to the way I wanted to.